# Apache virtual host + reverse proxy conflict

Tags: apache, jupyter

I have a server running ubuntu+apache. I have a website running (old ipython notebook with a multiuser-hack) that can be accessed through xxx.xx.xx.xx (=:myip). The corresponding apache configuration called `sins.conf` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ipython.local-server
    ServerAlias

    WSGIDaemonProcess ipythonapp2 user=www-data group=www-data processes=2 threads=5\
     python-path=/home/sins/ilmrt/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/sins/ilmrt/ipysite/wsgi.py
    <Directory /home/sins/ilmrt/ipysite>
    #WSGIProcessGroup ipythonapp2
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static/ /home/sins/ilmrt/ipysite/static/
    <Location "/static/">
        Options -Indexes
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

and works perfectly.

Now, since I'm about to run a new website (jupyterhub) with reverse proxy in addition, I setup a new apache configuration called `jupyterhub.conf`:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:9111/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9111/

Header edit Origin http://myip:9111/ localhost:9111
RequestHeader edit Origin http://myip:9111 localhost:9111

Header edit Referer http://myip:9111  localhost:9111
RequestHeader edit Referer http://myip:9111 localhost:9111
<Location ~ "/(user/[^/]*)/(api/kernels/[^/]+/channels|terminals/websocket)/?">
    ProxyPass ws://localhost:9111
    ProxyPassReverse ws://localhost:9111
</Location>
```

If i run `sudo a2ensite jupyterhub` and `sudo service apache2 reload`, the new website works as expected under http://myip:9111. However, the old website with the address http://myip shows *Service Unavailable*.

I don't understand what I need to change to make both sites working at the same time. Any help?

EDIT:
I believe I need to put the jupyterhub configuration inside a `<VirtualHost *:9111>`, but if I start the jupyterhub server it says
*Proxy appears to be running at http://myip:9111, but I can't access it. Connection refused.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the trick was as I assumed: It needs to be put in a VirtualHost.
For some reason I initially put a `Listen 9111` in front of the config-code below, which is why it blocked something..Here's the code in case anyone is interested:

```
<VirtualHost *:9111>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9111/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9111/

    Header edit Origin http://myip:9111/ localhost:9111
    RequestHeader edit Origin http://myip:9111 localhost:9111

    Header edit Referer http://myip:9111  localhost:9111
    RequestHeader edit Referer http://myip:9111 localhost:9111

    <Location ~ "/(user/[^/]*)/(api/kernels/[^/]+/channels|terminals/websocket)/?">
        ProxyPass ws://localhost:9111
        ProxyPassReverse ws://localhost:9111
    </Location>

    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: the Listen 9111 is great .It also resolve my problem!thanks a lot